# How to check if a pointer is free in C?

Tags: c

Is there a way to check if a pointer has been free before?

For example, if I run this code:

```
int* p = (int*)malloc(1000);
free(p);
p = (int*)realloc(p, 2000);
```

I get the error:

```
*** Error in `./main': realloc(): invalid old size: 0x00000000012ab010 ***
...
```

I would like to have an opportunity to check `p` before calling `realloc` to avoid such errors.

Comment: There is no need to cast the return of `malloc` or `realloc` (or `calloc`), it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how you check: Did you free it before? If so, it's been freed. If not, no.

C doesn't track this for you, so you may want to `NULL` out any pointers you `free` if you lose track of if you have or haven't released the associated memory.

C does the most minimal thing unless you spell out explicitly that you want it to do something more:

```
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Now you can test, but remember, it's your responsibility to do this, so if this behaviour is important, you must do it consistently.